# Scala - List Variable outside of foreach loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The code below isn't giving me the desired output. I am getting the output of `finallist` as individual characters separated by commas; I was expecting lists with two values only (filename, sizeofcolumn).

```
val pathurl="adl://*****.azuredatalakestore.net/<folder>/<sub_folder>"
val filelist=dbutils.fs.ls(pathurl)

val newdf = df.select("path").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList

var finallist = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Any]

newdf.foreach(f => {
    val MasterPq = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").parquet(f.toString())
    val size = MasterPq.columns.length
    val mergedlist = List(f.toString(), size.toString())

    mergedlist.map((x => {finallist = finallist ++ x}))

})

println(finallist)
```

Comment: can you post a sample input data and expected output?

Comment: The intention of the code is loop through the adls url and print a list with adls filename & respective column length of that file.
Here f is list[string] & size is INT. Sample input from the loop;
f = List("adl://*****.azuredatalakestore.net/<folder>/<sub_folder/file1_20180823_062535.025.done.snappy.parquet",adl://*****.azuredatalakestore.net/<folder>/<sub_folder/file2_20180824_062538.095.done.snappy.parquet")
size = 6

Comment: Excepted output:
List (adl://*****.azuredatalakestore.net/<folder>/<sub_folder/file1_20180823_062535.025.done.snappy.parquet, 6)
List (adl://*****.azuredatalakestore.net/<folder>/<sub_folder/file2_20180824_062538.095.done.snappy.parquet, 10)

Answer (score 2):

The bug in your code is that you're using the `++` method to append values to your list. This method is used to append two list.

```
scala> List(1, 2) ++ List(3, 4)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In scala strings are viewn as a list of characters, so your appending each individual character to your list.

```
scala> List(1, 2) ++ "Hello"
res3: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, H, e, l, l, o)
```

Since you're using a mutable list, you can append values with the '+=' method. If you just want to get your code working, than the following should be enough, but it is **not** a good solution.

```
// mergedlist.map((x => {finallist = finallist ++ x}))
mergedlist.map((x => finallist += x}))
```

You're probably new to scala, coming from a imperative language like Java. Scala collections do not work as you're known from such programming languages. Scala's collections are immutable by default. Instead of modifying collections, you're using using functions such as `map` to build new lists based on the old list.

The `map` function is one of the most used functions on lists. It takes an anonymous function as parameter that takes one element and transforms it to another value. This function is applied onto all methods of the list thereby build a new list. Here's an example:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3).map(i => i * 2)
list: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

In this example, a function that multiplies integers by two is applied onto each element in the list. The results are put into the new list. Maybe this illustration helps to comprehend the process:

```
List(1,    2,    3)
     |     |     |
    * 2   * 2   * 2
     ↓     ↓     ↓
List(2,    4,    6)
```

We could use the `map` function to solve your task.
We can use it to map each element in the `newdf` list into a tuple with the corresponding `(filename, filesize)`.

```
val finallist = newdf.map { f => 
    val masterPq = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").parquet(f.toString())
    val size = masterPq.columns.length
    (f.toString(), size.toString())
}
```

I think this code is shorter, simpler, easier to read and just way more beautiful. I will definitely recommend you to learn more about Scala's collections and immutable collections in general. Once you understand them, you'll just love them!